# Actionscript - JSON to complex object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to JSON encode and decode a `flash.geom.Rectange` object. When I decode the object, it is of type `Object`. If I try to cast it to `Rectangle`, I get a null object:

```
var rect:Rectangle = JSON.decode(json_string) as Rectangle;
```

It looks like I can't cast to a Rectangle from Object that has exactly same properties as Rectangle.

An option would be to copy properties from Object to Rectangle.

I'm looking at [introspection of objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html) however, iterating through object's properties only goes one level deep.  If an a property that is being copied is of type `Point`, the `Point`'s properties are not copied. Looks like I have to copy them recursively.

Is there a function in actionscript that would deep copy an object?

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer - No. You'll have to pass the components of the decoded JSON object into a new Rectangle.

```
var jRect:Object = JSON.decode(json_string);
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(jRect.x, jRect.y, jRect.width, jRect.height);
```

In this case you are lucky because the Points you mentioned are inferred from the constructor values. For more complex classes I usually make a class level fromJSON method.

Comment: this is the solution i went for because it is the easiest at the time. however i did create a copy method for more complex objects. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy function that I came up with. Tested it with a simple type like Rectangle. 
There is a try/catch statement there because I was getting exceptions when I would try to write to read-only properties. There should be an if statement to check if property is writable but I don't have the time or patience right now. I will come back to improve it later but for now here it is:

```
public static function copy(source:Object, dest:Object):void
{
    for (var prop in source)
    {
        if (getQualifiedClassName(source[prop]) == "Object")
        {
            copy(source[prop], dest[prop]);
        }
        else
        {
            try // bad. should really be an if statement to check if property is writable. 
            {
                dest[prop] = source[prop];
            }
            catch (err:Error)   {}
        }
    }       
}
```